# Is it necessary to use “the” before using verb

Tags: grammaticality, definite-articles

'The' is usually used before a noun. But in sentences that refer to specific action, is 'the' necessary?

Example:

> The release of the bending moment results in opening and closing of the pipe.

Answer (score 1):

In that sentence, *bending* is an adjective, modifying the noun *moment*, and the entire phrase begins with *the*, because it’s definite. (I can’t envisage a moment being released, but perhaps it makes sense in the context.)

Comment: Moment as in distance x force. Though 'release of' same still sounds peculiar. Release of pressure? Apparently, [closing bending moments](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0308016105000785) and opening bending moments merit their own initialisms.

Comment: Shows once again how important context is.